# Constraint NotBlank/NotNull on Entity field Symfony2

Tags: forms, symfony, entity, constraints

I have a User entity. Every User can belong to one Domain.

```
class User extends BaseUser implements DomainableInterface
{
    …

    /**
    * @var Domain
    *
    * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Domain", inversedBy="users")
    * @ORM\JoinColumns({
    *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="domain_id", referencedColumnName="id")
    * })
    */
    private $domain;

    …
}
```

When I create a User, I want the Domain to be mandatory. Here is the form (it's a Super Class because many other entities will belong to a Domain), the User form inherits from that one

```
abstract class HasDomainFormType extends AbstractType
{
    private $user;

    public function __construct($securityContext)
    {
        $this->user = $securityContext->getToken()->getUser();
    }

    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $user = $this->user;
        $builder
            ->add('domain', 'entity', array(
                    'class'    => 'AppBundle:Domain',
                    'property' => 'id',
                    'multiple' => false,
                    'query_builder' => function(DomainRepository $er) use ($user) {
                        if (!in_array('ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN', $user->getRoles())) {
                            return $er->createQueryBuilder('d')
                                    ->andWhere('d.id = :domainId')
                                    ->setParameter('domainId', $user->getDomain()->getId());
                        } else {
                            return $er->createQueryBuilder('d');
                        }
                    },
                )
            )
        ;
    }
}
```

And here is the validation.xml file

```
    <class name="AppBundle\Entity\User">
      <property name="domain">
          <constraint name="NotNull">
              <option name="message">fos_user.domain.blank</option>
              <option name="groups">
                  <value>Update</value>
              </option>
          </constraint>
        </property>
    </class>
```

When I submit the form omitting the domain field (it's a Rest API), I get this error :

```
An exception occurred while executing 'SELECT b0_.id AS id0, b0_.name AS name1, b0_.enabled AS enabled2 FROM bo_domain b0_ WHERE b0_.id IN (?)' with params [""]:
SQLSTATE[22P02]: Invalid text representation: 7 ERROR:  invalid input syntax for integer: ""
```

But everything works fine if I fill in the domain field.

I don't understand why. I would like the form to tell me that the field "domain" can not be null.

EDIT : The error occurs while I do

```
$form->handleRequest($request);
```

not at the

```
$form-isValid();
```

Comment: My first idea would be to look why `$user->getDomain()->getId()` return `""`. If `user` is authenticated user, does it have domain assigned?

Comment: I found an alternative way to do it. And I think I found why is the problem. I'll post answer

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't make it work, so I made a workaround.

```
abstract class HasDomainFormType extends AbstractType
{
    private $user;
    private $domainManager;

    public function __construct($securityContext, $domainManager)
    {
        $this->user = $securityContext->getToken()->getUser();
        $this->domainManager = $domainManager;
    }

    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $user = $this->user;

        $arrchoice = $this->domainManager->getDomainForUser($user);
        $builder
            ->add('domain', 'entity', array(
                    'class'    => 'AppBundle:Domain',
                    'property' => 'id',
                    'multiple' => false,
                    'choices'  => $arrchoice
                )
            )
        ;
    }
}
```

Instead of using the `query_builder` option, I fetch all the choices I need with the DomainManager before building the form, and I use them in the `choices` options.

Thanks to @Jovan Perovic, I think I know where the problem lies, though I haven't tested.
I'm using this form to create a User, so here is the line in my controller

```
$form = $this->createForm(new UserFormType(), $user);
```

My guess is that the `$user` variable in parameters override the `$user` variable I use in my FormType in the `query_builder` option. Since it's a new User, it does not have a domain.

If I get some time, I'll try to rename the `$user` in my form to `$currentUser`, and see if that works.